# Parsing JSON with different Token in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, c#-4.0

I am getting a response from Klout API.
The response has has the following fields

- Name
- Score
- ScoreDeltas

  - Day Change
  - Week Change
  - Month Change

I had created classes in .NET and I populate the objects with JSON response. This is working fine but sometimes there is not ScoreDeltas in my JSON response. How I cam check this on spot?

```
JavaScriptSerializer _jsserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var list = _jsserializer.Deserialize<List<KloutInfluencer>>(influencer as string);

//KloutInfluencer is the ckass with all fields.
```

It gives me `NullReference` at this

```
public double dayChange
{
    get { return entity.payload.scoreDeltas.dayChange ; }
}
```

This is because there is no ScoreDelta element in JSON response (for this id). How can I check that on runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - Handle within your property:

You could write something like this:

```
public double dayChange
{
    get { return entity.payload.scoreDeltas == null ? 0 : entity.payload.scoreDeltas.dayChange }
}
```

---

Option 2 - Handle after deserialization manually for all objects:

Actually you would need to decide on a default value - this is probably acceptable. You might manually work through your list setting the scoreDeltas to a new instance. Something like this:

```
list.ForEach( entry => entry.scoreDeltas = entry.scoreDeltas ?? new ScoreDealtas() );
// On my MAC currently, untested, should show an idea
```

---

Option 3 - Handle directly after deserialization within each object:

Microsoft also provides you with an interface that you can implement that is called when an object was deserialized (IDeserializationCallback, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx). If you implement this in the `KloutInfluencer` class, you could handle properties that where left null because the json does not provided a value for.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and look what is null? If you tried option 1 and still get a NullReferenceException, it be payload being null or entity.

Comment: No the payload is not null nor the enitty.The ScoreDeltas property is null

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `dayChange` property of the `KloutInfluencer` class to be nullable and just check if the `scoreDeltas` property of the payload is set.

```
public double? dayChange
{
    get
    {
        if (null == entity ||
            null == entity.payload ||
            null == entity.payload.scoreDeltas)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return entity.payload.scoreDeltas.dayChange;
    }
}
```